# Manipulate aborts the computation of NDSolve with the Piecewise function after curtain time

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, manipulate, piecewise

I'm facing the problem with performance: Manipulate is working fine till end time =60 sec, after that it aborts. There is NDSolve inside Manipulate with Piecewise function, and the plot of the interpolating functions. It all works fine if I fix the parameters and compute NDSolve and Plot separately, but I would be happy if it all works within Manipulate. What are the restrictions for Manipulate use?
 Thank you

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a[t_] = Sin[Pi t]^100;
b[t_] = Sin[Pi t]^4;
a1 = N[Integrate[a[t], {t, 0, 1}]];
b1 = N[Integrate[b[t], {t, 0, 1}]];
start = 0;
end = 70;
delta := RandomChoice[{0.08, -0.08, 0.16, -0.16}];
g[x_] = Piecewise[Table[{Sin[x Pi + delta]^100, i <= x < i + 1}, {i,start,end - 1}]];
Manipulate[
sol = SetPrecision[NDSolve[{
x'[t] == (k R2 g[t]/a1 x[t] (1 - x[t]- y[t])50(x[t])/(1 + 50 (x[t]))-m1 x[t],
y'[t] == (R2 b[t - c]/b1) y[t] (1 - x[t] - y[t]) 50 (y[t])/(1 + 50 (y[t])) - m1 y[t], 
 x[0] == s x0, y[0] == s (0.99 - x0)}, {x, y}, {t, start, end},
MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]], 5];

Plot[{ x[t] /. sol, y[t] /. sol}, {t, start, end},
PlotRange -> Automatic,  PlotPoints -> 4000,PlotLegends -> {Native,Invasive}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["t", 16, Italic],Style[Row[{Style["Native[t]", 16], " ,  ", tyle["Invasive[t]", 16]}], 16]},
Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 1 400 {1, 1},
ImagePadding -> {{40, Automatic}, {40, Automatic}}], 

{{R2,4}, {0.6, 1, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20}}, {{m1,0.3},0.1, 1}, {{x0, 0.144}, 0.03,0.97},
{{k, 5}, {0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 1, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5,10}}, 
{{c, 0.6}, 0.3, 0.8}, {s, 0.5, 1}
]
```

Comment: Use `Sin[x]^100` not `(Sin^100)[x]`

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of editing your old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the function evaluating at each point of plot instead of being set once and for all. This is due to the misuse of setdelayed (:=).

```
end = 5;
delta :=RandomChoice[{0.08, -0.08, 0.16, -0.16}];
f[x_] = Piecewise[
   Table[{Sin[x Pi + delta]^100, i <= x < i + 1}, {i, 0, end-1}]];

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, end}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

Comment: Thank you! But it's still doesn't plot it piecewise. I expect 1 plot line at a time, just 5 intervals on each of those the function is defined uniquily.

Comment: Right, see the edit.